# How to change nodeJS CLI prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to change the prompt for the `nodejs` cli prompt. I looked around but didn't find an solution.

Some people talked about a `prompt` module. But `var p = require('prompt');` just gives me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not using the p.start(); command. So try out this simple example

```
  var prompt = require('prompt');


  prompt.start();

  // 
  // Get two properties from the user: username and email 
  // 
  prompt.get(['username', 'email'], function (err, result) {
    // 
    // Log the results. 
    // 
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  email: ' + result.email);
  });
```

Also if you are new to npm and node in general, start your projects with

```
npm init
```

that creates your package.json file in which you provide your project's dependencies

the following command installs prompt for node and saves it in your package.json

```
npm install -S prompt
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this script as a startup file (similiar to `bashrc` or `irbrc`) whenever you start node?

Comment: No, I don't think node allows you to customize it's [REPL terminal] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_repl_terminal.htm) but you can still use it as a startup file to your application

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dependency to your project.

`[sudo] npm install prompt [--save]`

--save will add it to your package.json